# Create a WHERE OR IN postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, psql

Right now I have the query

```
DELETE FROM connections
WHERE "user_b_id" IN
(SELECT "id"
FROM   "users"
WHERE  'dharness.student@gmail.com'="email")
```

But what I really want is

```
WHERE "user_b_id" OR "user_a_id" IN ...
```

But I can't figure out how to make that work. Is there an operator for this?

Comment: That's perfect! Thankyou! Should I post this as the answer, or will you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If users.email is unique you can write

```
WHERE (SELECT id FROM users 
       WHERE email = 'dharness.student@gmail.com') 
   IN (user_b_id , user_a_id)
```

Comment: This will fail when this `SELECT id FROM users 
       WHERE email = 'dharness.student@gmail.com'` query returns more than one row. But practically that should never happen :)

Comment: @MotoGP: That's why I wrote *If users.id is unique* :-)

Comment: Even though ID is unique and Email is duplicated it will be a problem

Comment: @MotoGP: Yep, of course, I should change to *if users.email is unique*.

Comment: @MotoGP Thanks for your valuable feedback.do you have another one approach/query  to get rid from this

Comment: @User `SELECT *
FROM   connections C
       JOIN "users" u
         ON c."user_b_id" = u.id
             OR c.user_a_id = u.id `